# Determining a set of vectors

Tags: statistics, analysis

Suppose we have a set of three-dimensional vectors with a homogeneous structure:

```
1         -1.85499198        1.62793873        -2.0184048
2          1.83395521        1.42405165         1.2645851
3         -0.18605955       -1.12279312        -1.0993611
4         -1.35352967        1.49225082         1.9312498
5          1.03399469        3.13274932        -0.4376091
6          4.51672032       -0.08265989         0.4870010
7          0.77527317       -0.24674913        -2.2366769
8         -0.03998958        1.21099809        -0.1046074
9          1.58223212       -0.51506561        -0.4712925
10        -2.45544507       -1.20280099        -1.5075621
11         2.31201163        1.25493453        -1.0251216
12         0.96649987       -0.08195786        -1.3871948
13        -0.81536208        1.78298535         0.7638233
14        -1.26479667       -0.73749255         0.6957713
15         1.69679772       -0.17229799        -0.8861638
16         0.81791933       -2.48285287         0.8219811
17         0.26498642        0.28705815        -1.6778466
18         2.97086006       -0.72155781        -1.5325699
19        -0.44739035       -1.17057235        -2.4650920
```

(homogeneity is vague word in this situation, but I mean that sd's of components of vectors are of same scale -- 1.73, 1.37, 1.27, their mean's  are --  0.545, 0.193, -0.573, so they're about the same size. Plotting components as separate arrays shows no trend, no obvious cyclical structure). 
Also I have an array of integer numbers (19 of them):

```
 99 117  98  97  97 100  96  87 103 100 106  97 100  98 107 105  86  81  85
```

I want to determine a set of vectors with this property: a dot product of vector "i" from the given set with vector "i" from new set is equal to number "i" from the array. Also the idea was that this new set has to be in the same sense homogeneous. The most obvious solution is to divide given set into groups of 3 vectors (with consecutive numbers: 1-2-3, 2-3-4 etc.), consider this group with 3 corresponding numbers from array as a linear system, solve it and we get a vector that has wanted property. But the problem is that when we've done it we get a set of 17 vectors (two less than a given set because there are only 17 groups of 3) and they are not homogeneous: sd's of components of obtained vectors: 203.73, 369.22, 478.11. I can attach graphs but it's obvious that something more thought-out should be done.

Comment: Hmm. This is an interesting problem: the problem is to solve an underdetermined system (i.e. fewer equations than variables) of linear equations, subject to additional, nonlinear, constraints. More specifically you have 3*19 variables (one for each component of each vector) and 19 equations, subject to the sum of each column being equal, and the sum of squares of each column being equal (these two conditions are enough to make the new columns homogeneous in the sense you described). Maybe singular value decomposition is relevant here? Or the augmented Lagrangian method? Dunno for sure.

Comment: What you mean by "subject to the sum of each column"? Yeah, I thought about sum of squares as an indicator of this sort of homogeneity. It's great that you confirmed my suspicions. I'll read about augmented Lagrangian method, thanks, never heard of it. But how SVD can be applied here?

Comment: "Subject to the sum of each column" because you want the means of the columns to match up. SVD seems relevant because underdetermined systems can be solved via SVD -- a web search for "underdetermined system SVD" should turn up some hits. The additional constraints complicate the problem; I don't know if SVD is still applicable to the constrained problem. The augmented Lagrangian method is applicable to smooth optimization problems with equality constraints. In this picture the function to be minimized is the square of the norm of A x - y with obvious notation (sorry, I have to catch a bus).

Comment: @RobertDodier, I've just read about combining SVD and QR-decomposition to implement least-square method. It is very powerful combination) It needs some non-trivial modification to be applicable to the current problem but I believe it's possible)